# Matching urls including query string in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I have a custom router (implementing `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Interface`) and I want:

- this url `/foo?action=bar` to be routed to `{module->a, controller->b, action->bar}`
- whereas url `/foo` is routed to `{module->a, controller->b, action->c}`

**i.e.** `action` param in query string (if present) is determining the default action.

I am using the `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite` router and the problem is that it passes only pathInfo (i.e. no query string) to the `match()` method of the router.

I can get a request object from the front controller manually and extract the 'action' param, but is there a better way how to solve this issue?